# How to solve "All hosts are taken by other resources" on Google Cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, lets-encrypt, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I currently have a Kubernetes cluster running on GCP. In this cluster I have a working NGINX Ingress, but now I'm trying add a certificate to this by using cert-manager.

Everything works fine except the ACME challenge.
When I do a `kubectl describe challenge` I get the following:

```
Status:
  Presented:   true
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request
```

When the acme challenge creates a solver service I get the follow error message on GCP:

```
"All hosts are taken by other resources"
```

[Image of the error I'm getting in google cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0p5f.png)

I have tried to create a **Issuer** and **ClusterIssuer** but the same problem keeps popping up.

Comment: After testing a bit I have figured out that when you delete the ingress that is currently running the ```acme challenge``` does proceed and get validated. After that I recreated the Ingress and everything seemed to work just fine. This however is not best practice. Still looking for a valid solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After trying to solve the issues and browsing the web, I have figured out the solution.
It is possible to add the following annotation:

```
annotations:
  acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
```

After adding this line to my Ingress resource everything seemed to work perfectly.
When this annotation is not passed in, cert-manager will create an extra Ingress for the acme challenge

See: [Cert-manager, using an Ingress](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/ingress/#:%7E:text=acme.cert%2Dmanager.io%2Fhttp01%2Dedit%2D,the%20annotation%20assumes%20%E2%80%9Cfalse%E2%80%9D.)